Graphics drivers with Ubuntu 20.04
I recently got a new Lenovo Thinkpad X1C gen11 with Intel Iris Xe integrated graphics and a 13th-gen Intel Core i7 processor. For my studies I need Ubuntu 20.04. All the features work well in Ubuntu except for the graphics. The kernel does not seem to recognize the integrated graphics and uses llvmpipe instead which makes degrades the experience significantly.
I know that the newer versions of Ubuntu should support this hardware. Which is why I my best guess was to install the newest kernel version possible. (I don't know exactly if that works as I expect it to)
I tried to install the OEM drivers and also newer driver versions, but nothing seems to help.
Does anyone have an idea or experience to get the system to recognize and use the integrated graphics?
This is some system information, note I am pretty new to this so please also state obvious misconfigurations:
~$ uname -r
6.9.11-060911-generic

~$ inxi --graphics
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: fbdev 
  unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 2880x1800~90Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0 256 bits) 
  v: 4.5 Mesa 22.2.0-devel (git-08da37035f)

*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=2880x1800 visual=truecolor xres=2880 yres=1800
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:187 memory:603d000000-603dffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff

Please if you need some additional information or have any idea what to try differently, tell me!
Thank you in advance for your help!
FIX: I got it to work. There is a specific intel kernel which can be installed with:
sudo apt install linux-header-intel
sudo apt install linux-image-intel

It works now, I don't know if this is a clean or particularly stable fix but it works for now. I hope to update soon anyway...

The fix mentioned above worked for me on my Thinkpad E14 gen5 laptop with intel iris xe graphics on Ubuntu 20.04.6 OS. Installing the new kernel upgraded the kernel to 5.15.0-1062-intel-iotg. I can now use the brightness keys on my keyboard and change screen resolution. Renderer shown in the settings UI and result of inxi --graphics is Mesa Intel® Graphics (RPL-P).

For me, only linux-image-intel was needed, thanks for the fix! For more visibility you could post an answer and mark your question as solved
